# Unable to boot Galaxy S - only see a picture of phone -> "triangle with an exclamation point" -> computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I just bought a Galaxy S phone for my son last month.  He was trying to download Clockworkmod firmware and probably loaded the wrong version.  It initially was in a boot loop.  After I took it to the dealer, an inexperience staff tried to reset the phone back to factory mode.  The manager saw the hat logo on the phone and stopped us right there.  The manager told us that we void the warranty by downloading an authorized software.

Now, when we power up the phone, we wonly see a picture of the phone -> "triangle with an exclamation point" -> computer" .  There are no other responses.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Did you try removing the battery and reinseting it again?

Comment: Can you specify what version of the Galaxy S?  Is it the international GT-i9000?  What you're seeing is Download Mode, by the way.

Comment: @Matthew Not necessarily... Kernel Panic error etc displays same screen...

Comment: Next time only follow instructions on flashing from sites like XDA Forum(http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Now, the only option you've left is to Flash your ROM. Flash any one of OFFICIAL firmware from below:

- [Gingerbread 2.3.5 XFJVA](http://androidadvices.com/update-samsung-galaxy-i9000-official-gingerbread-235-xfjva-firmware/2/)
- [Gingerbread 2.3.5 XXJVT](http://androidadvices.com/samsung-galaxy-gt-i9000-steps-install-gingerbread-235-xxjvt-firmware/3/)

Follow the links & do EXACTLY what it says. It'll take less that half an hour. Just, do it.. Nothing more!

Don't do any experiment before you boot your device. Plus, don't follow any non-matured instructions from forums etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look up your phone's PIT in Google and put it in pit in [odin](/questions/tagged/odin). Flash it, then flash your ROM.

In case your battery is not charging: look for someone to charge it for you in his device before you do this as it consumes battery power with the constant rebooting of the yellow triangle.